# Redirect from one inline site to another inline site

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect users trying to access http://example.com/car/ to http://example.com/car/blue/ in .htaccess

I have tried the following which I thought would work:

```
Redirect 301 "/car/"  http://www.example.com/car/blue/
Redirect 301 /car/ http://www.example.com/car/blue/
```

Non of them work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have mod_rewrite enabled try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://www.example.com/car/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^http://www.example.com/car/$ http://www.example.com/car/blue [R=301,L]
```